# Comparing Object in Mongoose with DateTime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

that's my MongoDB Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DogSchema = new Schema({
    id_user: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    imei: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    position: [{
        lat: {type: Number, required:true},
        lng: {type: Number, required:true},
        date: {type: Date, required:true}
    }],
    teams: [{
        code: {type:String,required:true}
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dog', DogSchema);
```

I want to find only Positions in a specific Date range.
I tried to use the query:

```
db.dogs.find({"position.date" : { $gte : new Date("2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z") , $lt : new Date("2017-11-26T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

But, if i find a position that match the query, the DB return all the document. How can i get only the positions with that date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the conditions for the query within your subdocuments you must use `.populate()` with `match`

```
  db.dogs.find({}).
  populate({
    path: "position",
    match: { date: { $gte : new Date("2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z") , $lt : new Date("2017-11-26T00:00:00.000Z") }},
    // Explicitly exclude `_id` if needed
    select: '-_id date',
  }).
  exec()
```

see [Mongoose Query Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)